# Xcode 9 storyboard window position autosave

Tags: macos, cocoa, storyboard, xcode9

I start new project in Xcode 9 (macOS Game with SceneKit technology). I got storyboard containing `NSWindowController` with `NSWindow` and related `GameViewController` with `SCNView`. Project runs fine (spins a plane).

Now in storyboard I set Autosave value to "MainWindow" for `NSWindow`, run project, resize window and then quit. I know that with Autosave set on quit window position will be saved using `NSUserDefaults`, so I check in Terminal:

```
$ defaults read com.koati.Bloks                                           ⏎
{
    "NSWindow Frame MainWindow" = "415 228 450 322 0 0 1280 777 ";
}
```

That's expected behaviour. Now I run project once again, but I see that window position is not restored. If in storyboard I remove `GameViewController` relation, then position is saved and restored correctly, so I suppose that `GameViewController` somehow influences window size and position.
In older Xcode with XIBs there were no such problem.

**EDIT:** After some doing some tests, I now think it is not related to SceneKit at all, as replacing `SCNView` with `NSView` in `NSViewController` produces same results. So I think the problem is that `NSViewController` attached via Storyboard to `NSWindow` content influences window position and size.

Maybe some one knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: I experience the same issue, and agree with your observation. I've got a testproject for this issue. Default from template: Window->View Controller->View preserves the position and size.
If I replace to Window->Split View Controller->View it doesn't preserve position and size (always return to default position and size).
If I do it Window->View Controller->View->Container View->Split View Controller->View, again, it preserves size and position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strangely enough, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33707356/3736845
still applies, even in XCode9. After programmatic setup of autosave name (for Swift4 a bit different notation):

```
class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

  override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()

    // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    self.windowFrameAutosaveName = NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName.init(rawValue: "position")
  }
}
```

it started restoring positions on restart of the Application.

What I don't understand however is what's saved into defaults:

```
defaults read com.ne.TestWindowPosition
{
   "NSWindow Frame Position" = "510 428 901 322 0 0 1920 1177 ";
   "NSWindow Frame position" = "0 0 901 322 0 0 1920 1177 ";
}
```

I played a bit with the IB Window Autosave identifier - you see it appears as first line in the defaults ("Position") and it doesn't seem to be read properly on Application startup.
After I added manual set of autosave name to "position" - it's changing, when I move the window.

Comment: Bad thing is that I need to use additional NSWindowController just to implement default IB functionality. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug that's still in Xcode 10. Here's what worked for me (in Xcode 10, in a macOS Cocoa project using storyboards):

• No value set in the storyboard's window's autosave field.

• Use a custom window controller class as below.

```
import AppKit


class WindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Workaround for a bug in autosave default for window frame:
        window!.setFrameAutosaveName("position")
        // It has to be "position" here in code, and no value in storyboard.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that each name of the frame must be unique. Meaning, if you have multiple windows, create a class for each window with its own name. Probably not the prettiest solution, but it works well if you only have a few other windows in your Mac app.